# CodeIgniter incorrect output num_rows == 1

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What's wrong with this code why it returns num_rows == 0.

```
function validate() 
    {

        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('userpassword', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('tbluser'); 


        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }


    }
```

here is my database screenshot

[image]

Also Screenshot of my query executing in mysql

[image]

Comment: after `get()` use `echo $this->db->last_query()` to check what sql query is executed.

Comment: where should i put that ? i separated it in my view ? can it be displayed to my view page?

Comment: You can use for testing only. after `get()` add it and put `exit;`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `tbluser` WHERE `username` = 'john' AND `userpassword` = '527bd5b5d689e2c32ae974c6229ff785' this is the output sir.

Comment: means it is working fine so use `$query->num_rows()` instead of `$query->num_rows`.

Comment: thanks sir. I manage to display my query :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the **()**. It should `be $query->num_rows()`

```
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

The reason it's returning 0 is because `$query->num_rows` does not exist(*that results to false or 0*).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = $this->db->get('tbluser')->result_array();


if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
$query  = $this -> db
           -> select('*')
           -> where(
                array(
                    'username'=> $this->input->post('username')
                    'userpassword'=> md5($this->input->post('password')
                )
            )
           -> get('tbluser');
```